# Can´t get the html selectors right using Puppetter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I started to learn puppetter recently following a tutorial. The tutorial code that I followed worked but I tried to write and similar code that didn´t.

TUTORIAL CODE:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, 
        defaultViewport: false,
        userDataDir: "./tmp"
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A16225007011&fs=true&ref=1p_16225007011_sar');

    const productsHandles = await page.$$( "div.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row > .s-result-item");

    for(const producthandle of productsHandles) {
        try {
            const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector('h2 > a > span').textContent, producthandle)
  
            console.log(title)
        } 
        catch (error) {
      
        }
    }
    //await browser.close()
})();
```

MY CODE:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, 
        defaultViewport: false,
        userDataDir: "./tmp"
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.superanimes.biz/lista-de-animes');

    const productsHandles = await page.$$("#containerVideos > section > section > div.post_cat.notranslate");

    for(const producthandle of productsHandles) {
        try {
      
            const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector('div.title_cat > span').textContent, producthandle)
            // #video_ > a > div.title_cat > span
            console.log(title)
        } 
        catch (error) {
      
        }
    }
    //await browser.close()
})();
```

It was supposed to loop to the elements and return the title of each one

It was supposed to loop through each one of the elements but my code just printed the first

Comment: the tutorial I used: https://youtu.be/nl3ZuHXHVSU?si=BThpjpM44a7epOfk

Comment: What does your html look like? Is there an error? I see a try/catch, but nothing handled in the catch.

Comment: The website gives "Sorry, you have been blocked. You are unable to access superanimes.biz" for me in USA. As suggested above, always `console.error(err)` in your `catch(err)` block. That's critical info! You may need to use `waitForSelector` or `waitForFunction` here, or scroll the page, or dip into an iframe, or one of many other possibilities.

Comment: @mykaf there is no html, i´m making a webscrapping script

Comment: @ggorlen I didn´t really know this was important thank you

Comment: If you are using css selectors, there must be html you are attempting to retrieve, whether it's your own code or not. How do you know what selectors to use? Please include the relevant html in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial does prints the title but remember that doing `page.evaluate()` inside for loop will make the `page.evaluate()` running over and over. This will make the code run takes too much CPU and costly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: false,
            userDataDir: "./tmp"
        })
        const superanimes = 'https://www.superanimes.biz/lista-de-animes'
        const selector = '#containerVideos > section > section > .post_cat.notranslate > .video_poster'
        const titles = 'a > div.title_cat > span'
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(superanimes)
        await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true})
        const productsHandles = await page.$$(selector)
        for (const producthandle of productsHandles) {
            const title = await page.evaluate((element) => {
                return element.querySelector(titles).textContent
            }, producthandle)
            console.log(title)
        }
        await browser.close()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
})()
```

So, I've modified the code to make it lighter and definitely will run so much faster.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: false,
            userDataDir: "./tmp"
        })
        const blockedResources = ['media', 'font', 'image']
        const superanimes = 'https://www.superanimes.biz/lista-de-animes'
        const selector = '#containerVideos > section > section > .post_cat.notranslate > .video_poster'
        const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
        await page.setRequestInterception(true)
        page.on('request', async (request) => {
            const resourceType = request.resourceType()
            if (blockedResources.includes(resourceType)) {
                request.abort()
            } else {
                request.continue()
            }
        })
        await page.goto(superanimes)
        await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true})
        const products = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
            const productHandle = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
            const products = []
            productHandle.forEach((product) => {
                products.push({
                    title: product.querySelector('a > div.title_cat > span').textContent,
                    link: product.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')
                })
            })
            return products
        }, selector)
        for (const product of products) {
            console.log(product.title)
        }
        await browser.close()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
})()
```